# PHP and SQLSRV isn't inserting all the rows it should

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I'm utilizing PHP 5.5 and connecting to a MS SQL database.  Connection works as expected.  I'm attempting to do a mass insert (around 2000 rows).  Rather than using PHP to run 2000 INSERT statements, I'm sending a query like so:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
WHILE(@count < 2000)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2)
VALUES ('data1', 'data2')
SET @count = (@count + 1)
END
```

When I plug this query directly into SQL Server Mangement Studio, it inserts 2000 rows as expected.  When I run the query via PHP like so:

```
$connectInfo = array ("UID"=>'user',"PWD"=>'@pass',"Database"=>"database", "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true);
$link = sqlsrv_connect("dataserver",$connectInfo);

$query = "DECLARE @count INT 
SET @count = 0  
WHILE(@count < 2000) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO License (Field1, Field2) 
VALUES('data1','data2') 
SET @count = (@count + 1) 
END";

if(!$foo = sqlsrv_query($link,$query)) {
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
  die("hooray beer time!");
}
```

This only inserts 524 rows in the table, not the expected 2000 (and some times it's 309 rows, X rows, its erratic).  It doesn't error out, and I get "hooray beer time!" after every script run.  By default, sqlsrv_query() function has no time limits, I thought.  Has anyone run into anything like this before?  It has me baffled.

Comment: This is valid sql. If it was a connection/command timeout or buffer size issue you would receive an exception. I would start by creating a testing stored procedure and pasting your sql. Then change your inline sql to"EXEC TEST_PROC" and see if there is any difference :(

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, it seems that after each insert in the While loop, SQL returns a little row of Text that says (1) row affected (or something to that tune).  Turning this off via:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

has remedied this issue.  Thanks all!